# I want to create a click-to-activate menu in HTML

Tags: html, menu, onclick

Please refer to the image below. [image]

I want users to click on an option in the "Metro Station Landmark", and the area under "Metro Station Info" will show the appropriate information.

For now I have only coded 2 of the sections for testing purposes.

```html
<!-- Start Pat Metro -->
                <section class="lattest-product-area pb-40 category-list">
                    <a id="patBase">
                        <div class="div-border div-border-indent">
                            <img src="img/gif/pat_metro.gif" class="resize">
                            <div style="padding-top: 4px;"></div>
                                <p>Coordinates: -354 69 -380 <br>
                                <u class="uline">Pathways</u><br>
                                To Shopping District: Do nothing.<br>
                                To Mr_Patcher's base: Goto Shopping District. From the Shooping District, press the 2nd button.<br>
                                To Shaunic's base: As soon as the cart stops, press the button.</p>                     
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </section>
                <!-- End Pat metro -->
                
                <!-- Start Farook Metro -->
                <section class="lattest-product-area pb-40 category-list">
                    <a id="farookBase">
                        <div class="div-border div-border-indent">
                            <img src="img/gif/farook_metro.gif" class="resize">
                            <div style="padding-top: 4px;"></div>
                                <p>Coordinates: -354 69 -380 <br>
                                <u class="uline">Pathways</u><br>
                                To Shopping District: Do nothing.<br>
                                To Mr_Patcher's base: Goto Shopping District. From the Shooping District, press the 2nd button.<br>
                                To Shaunic's base: As soon as the cart stops, press the button.</p>                     
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </section>
                <!-- End Farook metro -->
```

Alright so for now, when I load the page, both of the sections are displayed by default. If I click on one of the options, the linked section disappears and if I click it again, it reappears.

I feel like I have it somewhat figured out, so it would be helpful if anyone could tell me what I will have to do, to make it so that if someone clicks on one of the options, only the linked section is displayed.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think you may wish to use `scrollIntoView` on the `<a>`s.  look here: [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)  `document.getElementById("farookBase").scrollIntoview(true)`

Comment: @iAmOren I'm still new to web development. Could you maybe elaborate on how I could exactly implement this? THe documentation in the link is too much for me lol

Comment: I thought I did...  Left side menu `<a onclick='document.getElementById("farookBase").scrollIntoview(true)'>Farook Base</a>`.  Right side `<a id="farookBase">`.  why `<a>` here?  You can put the `id` in the `<section>` - `<section id="farookBase" class=".......">` (instead of the `<a>` - unless it's needed for a reason I can't see.).